# The value of the pointer to char address

Tags: c++, pointers

In VS C++ I have a simple declaration of a char variable and a pointer to char.

```
char mychar = 'c';
char *mypointer = &mychar;
```

When printing the value of mypointer using cout I would expect an 8 character address value like 0038FEDC to appear in console. Instead I am getting some strange results like:

> c│■8, ck∙<, c;■8 etc...

Why these strange characters appear when outputting pointer to char values?

Comment: Because `mypointer` is a `char *`, the `cout` system assumes it is a pointer to a null-terminated string of characters, so it prints the `c` that it does point to and all sorts of junk that belongs to other variables.  You could try casting to `void *`; that should probably print as a pointer: `cout << (void *)mypointer << endl;`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot. Your comment is as valuable as juanchopanza's answer.

Comment: Note that my C-style cast is sub-optimal for C++; you should probably use a `static_cast<void *>(mypointer)` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wouldn't agree it is a duplicate. My question addresses a pointer to single character, not a pointer to null terminated constant string literals.

Comment: OK; we disagree. I guess it depends what you want.  If you want to print a single character via a `char *`, then use `cout << *mypointer;` but if you expect an address (as your question suggests), then you have to request `cout << static_cast<void *>(mypointer);` or equivalent.  You can't expect an address and then complain when you're told how to print an address instead of junk.  Given your mention of expecting an address, I think the duplicate is appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::ostream`, of which `std::cout` is an instance, has an overload for `operator<<` which treats `char*` as a pointer to the first character in a *null-terminated string*.

You are passing it a pointer of a single character, not a null terminated string. This causes undefined behaviour.

In practice what is likely to happen is that a stream of characters will be printed out by treating the memory starting from `mychar` as an array of `char` and iterating over it, until a `\0` is found.

If you want to print the address, you can cast the pointer to something that isn't `char*`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(mypointer) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Isn't `static_cast` more appropriate here?

Comment: @zenith Could be. I don't think it matters here but it might be clearer. I'll change it.